# Binary file size

Tags: mysql

I have added the following option in order to avoid having smaller multiple binary files.

```
max_binlog_size=1024M
```

But MySQL still does not create a huge binary file as expected. How do I make it create a single file instead of multiple small files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL manual says

> The server creates a new file in the
>   series each time it starts or flushes
>   the logs

So, actually, you cannot control the size of binary log. Server should not start a new file until a log is flushed, server restarted or max_binlog_size reached whatever comes first.

Why do you need such degree of control, BTW?